# Average of every x rows with a step size of y per each subset using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
Subset  Position    Value
1   1   2
1   10  3
1   15  0.285714
1   43  1
1   48  0
1   89  2
1   132 2
1   152 0.285714
1   189 0.133333
1   200 0
2   1   0.133333
2   10  0
2   15  2
2   33  2
2   36  0.285714
2   72  2
2   132 0.133333
2   152 0.133333
2   220 3
2   250 8
2   350 6
2   750 0
```

I want to know how can I get the mean of values for every "x" row with "y" step size per subset in pandas?

For example, mean of every 5 rows (step size =2) for value column in each subset like this:

```
Subset  Start_position  End_position    Mean
1   1   48  1.2571428
1   15  132 1.0571428
1   48  189 0.8838094
2   1   36  0.8838094
2   15  132 1.2838094
2   36  220 1.110476
2   132 350 3.4533332
```

Comment: Shouldnt the last one be 350 instead of 750 ? And it should be 132 instead of 152?

Comment: @Joe Ferndz sorry, yes I should edit it.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Both moving windows and step size are covered in existing SO questions.

Comment: Now that we have established what the correct output looks like, I think I understand the ask. Have you done any research or work to solve it. If so, can you share that with us please.

Comment: @Joe Ferndz, the rolling function was what I have found in StackOverflow. however I coud not find the step size option for this. Additionally, there were other options but not using pandas. Actually, I want to solve this problem in Modin which its scripts is similar to pandas.

Comment: @Joe Ferndz also I defined a function to make start and end position (win and step size) using itertools and collections libraries but I do not know how can I apply them in Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Subset': [1]*10+[2]*12,
                   'Position': [1,10,15,43,48,89,132,152,189,200,1,10,15,33,36,72,132,152,220,250,350,750],
                   'Value': [2,3,.285714,1,0,2,2,.285714,.1333333,0,0.133333,0,2,2,.285714,2,.133333,.133333,3,8,6,0]})

averaged_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Subset', 'Start_position', 'End_position', 'Mean'])

window = 5
step_size = 2
for subset in df.Subset.unique():
    subset_df = df[df.Subset==subset].reset_index(drop=True)
    for i in range(0,len(df),step_size):
        window_rows = subset_df.iloc[i:i+window]
        if len(window_rows) < window:
            continue
            
        window_average = {'Subset': window_rows.Subset.loc[0+i],
                          'Start_position': window_rows.Position[0+i],
                          'End_position': window_rows.Position.iloc[-1],
                          'Mean': window_rows.Value.mean()}
        averaged_df = averaged_df.append(window_average,ignore_index=True)
```

Some notes about the code:

- It assumes all subsets are in order in the original df (`1,1,2,1,2,2` will behave as if it was `1,1,1,2,2,2`)
- If there is a group left that's smaller than a window, it will skip it (e.g. `1, 132, 200, 0,60476` is not included`)

Answer (score 2):

One version specific answer would be, using [`pandas.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer.html) introduced in `pandas 1.1.0`:

```
>>> window=5
>>> step=2
>>> indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=window)
>>> df2 = df.join(df.Position.shift(-(window-1)), lsuffix='_start', rsuffix='_end')
>>> df2 = df2.assign(Mean=df2.pop('Value').rolling(window=indexer).mean()).iloc[::step]
>>> df2 = df2[df2.Position_start.lt(df2.Position_end)].dropna()
>>> df2['Position_end'] = df2['Position_end'].astype(int)

>>> df2

    Subset  Position_start  Position_end      Mean
0        1               1            48  1.257143
2        1              15           132  1.057143
4        1              48           189  0.883809
10       2               1            36  0.883809
12       2              15           132  1.283809
14       2              36           220  1.110476
16       2             132           350  3.453333
```